# Javascript code for limit selection of icons onclick eventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML; I have tried to write some JavaScript to select up to 14 icons, and toggle the class from "text-muted" to "text-primary". After 14 icons have been selected it will become disabled, and no more toggle between the classes will work.

If we select the 14 icons after deselecting it will again allow me to select one more to complete the 14 but not more than 14.

```js
var icons = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-baby");


for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {

  icons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    if (icons[i] === 14 || icons[i] > 14) {

      this.style.classList.add("text-muted");

    } else {

      this.style.classList.toggle("text-primary");

    }
  })
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table ">

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
          <select class="mdl-textfield__input" id="octane2" name="octane2">
            <option value="Mar 2019">Mar 2019</option>
            <option value="Apr 2019">Apr 2019</option>
            <option value="Mai 2019">Mai 2019</option>
            <option value="Jun 2019">Jun 2019</option>
            <option value="Jul 2019">Jul 2019</option>
            <option value="Aug 2019">Aug 2019</option>
            <option value="Sep 2019">Sep 2019</option>
            <option value="okt 2019">Okt 2019</option>
            <option value="Nov 2019">Nov 2019</option>
            <option value="Dez 2019">Dec 2019</option>
            <option value="Jan 2020">Jan 2020</option>
            <option value="Feb 2020">Feb 2020</option>
            <option value="March 2020">Mar 2020</option>
            <option value="March 2020">Apr 2020</option>
          </select>
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="octane2">Geschlecht</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>April 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>May 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>June 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>July 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Auguest 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Setember 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>October 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>November 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>December 2019</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>January 2020</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Febuary 2020</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>March 2020</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>April 2020</p>
      </td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-3x"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please provide more information or a fiddle demonstrating the current state. When is the above JS triggered? Based from what I see I assume your if condition is wrong. You aren't checking for the count but rather on the DOM element. `if(i >= 14)` should basically be the right condition. However this will not work because you have to take your `text-muded` or `text-primary` classes into account otherwise you won't know which one is selected or not. This is just a basic idea. But as said there isn't enough information.

Comment: Please reformat the code, so it can be read more easily. Don't forget, you're asking for help here. So do your best to make helping you as easy and pleasant as possible.

Comment: can you please provide me the code i want to limit the icon selection. The toggle class is working but the if condition is making problem it is not executing i checked the console by console.log inside if condition.

Comment: int <=> let  : `for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) `

Comment: @muazbutt As already said, please state your question with enough information so that we can answer it. We can't provide you code or help if we don't know what you even need or want to achieve.

Comment: @MrJ Didn't notice that the data type is there and won't work in JS I'm Java damaged you're totally right on this :D

Comment: @thex i want to change the class on selection of the icons. but the selected icons will be upto limit 14 no more icons will be selected when 14 icons are selected.
second thing when 14 icons are selected more icons i can select only if i can deselect some from my existing icons. Hope you understand this time.

Comment: @muazbutt Ok thanks for updating your question. And now read what MrJ said. You have syntax errors in your code. That's the first thing to check. Second thing read my answer from above. This won't work because you should check on the count (not the element) and have to consider the classes which are already set (either `text-muted` or `text-primary`) otherwise you wouldn't get the correct count.

Comment: @thex Sorry but i am not getting can you please explain with code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: icons[i] === 14  is nonsense, because this an object, not a number with value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now created a basic example which should do what you want. Instead of using the `text-primary` and `text-muted` I used a specific CSS class to colourize. This is how the JS could look like so that you can achieve what you want:

```
var icons = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-baby");

for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
  icons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let ctn = document.getElementsByClassName("green").length;
    if (this.classList.contains("green")) {
      this.classList.remove("green");
    }else if(ctn < 14){
      this.classList.add("green");
    }
  });
}
```

You have to determine the `count` of selected elements e.g. `green` and check on the current count every time you click on an element. I added this new CSS class to better demonstrate the selection as for me the `text-muted` and `text-primary` didn't get the correct result. Maybe I did some mistake but even thought this highlighting is better for demonstration. A final solution might adapt the CSS class adding and removing. Additionally the code can probably be simplified or improved. It should only be a food for thought.

```
.green{
  color: green;
}
```

Here is the full fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/khwd9tam/

Comment: Thanks bro it worked. Really helpful appreciate your help. Also i am sorry i didn't include the necessary information because i don't know about that. Next time i will kept that in mind. again thanks.

Comment: @muazbutt You are welcome. No problem you are new here and therefore I tried to politely point you in the right direction so that we can easier help you. It's nothing bad but it's hard to find out what you want without proper question ;). If this solves it for you please mark as solved. thx.

Comment: I have one more problem brother in this regarding the dates. Should i post another question ?

Comment: @muazbutt Please open another question, not mixing up stuff here.

Comment: I upVote too, because I must admit that your code inspired mine ;)

Answer (score 1):

the  "*Best* " answer ... :)

```
const
  MaxBabys = 14
  ,
  iconBabys = document.querySelectorAll('td>i.fa-baby') // Be precise, babies can be anywhere!
  ,
  BabysCount = {
      count : 0,
      onClick(e)
      {
        let ClassElm = e.target.classList;

        if (ClassElm.contains('text-primary'))
        {
          ClassElm.remove('text-primary');
          ClassElm.add('text-muted');
          this.count--;
        }
        else if (MaxBabys > this.count)
        {
          ClassElm.remove('text-muted');
          ClassElm.add('text-primary');
          this.count++;
        }
        else
          { alert(` Babies limit !  (${MaxBabys})`) }
      }
    }
  ;

iconBabys.forEach( Baby_X=>{
  Baby_X.addEventListener('click', e=>{BabysCount.onClick(e)})
});
```

for info :

```
iconBabys.forEach( Baby_X=>{...
```

is equivalent to :

```
for (let i=0, iMax=iconBabys.length; i <iMax ; i++)
{
  let Baby_X = iconBabys[i];
  Baby_X.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    BabysCount.onClick(e)
  })
}
```

```js
const
  MaxBabys = 14
  ,
  iconBabys = document.querySelectorAll('td>i.fa-baby') // Be precise, babies can be anywhere!
  ,
  BabysCount = {
      count : 0,
      onClick(e)
      {
        let ClassElm = e.target.classList;

        if (ClassElm.contains('text-primary'))
        {
          ClassElm.remove('text-primary');
          ClassElm.add('text-muted');
          this.count--;
        }
        else if (MaxBabys > this.count)
        {
          ClassElm.remove('text-muted');
          ClassElm.add('text-primary');
          this.count++;
        }
        else
          { alert(` Babies limit !  (${MaxBabys})`) }
      }
    }
  ;

iconBabys.forEach( Baby_X=>{
  Baby_X.addEventListener('click', e=>{BabysCount.onClick(e)})
});
```

```css
table { font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif }
th { background-color:teal; color: yellow;padding: 10px; font-size: 24px }
td { background-color: rgb(228, 224, 224); padding: 0 10px; font-size: 12px}
td p { margin: 8px; font-size: 18px}
.text-muted { color:lightslategrey }
.text-primary { color:green }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table ">
  <thead>
      <tr> <th colspan="3">Geschlecht</th> </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><p>March 2019</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>April 2019</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>May 2019</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>June 2019</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>July 2019</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Auguest 2019</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Setember 2019</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>October 2019</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>November 2019</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>December 2019</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>January 2020</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>Febuary 2020</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>March 2020</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><p>April 2020</p></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
      <td><i class="text-muted fas fa-baby fa-2x"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer however it would've been complete if you had used `for` instead of the arrow function as we don't now the target browser version :P. Never be too sure using the word EXACT!

Comment: It is true, but we must leave a little room for humor and exaggeration ;) ... and everyone made here is with a loop `for`, i just made this for diversity

Comment: Of course we must / should and that's why I wrote this ;). Don't take my comment as a serious one :P. Wasn't intended this way either.

Comment: haha stop freaking out or I will reconsider my upvote :D. PS you forgot const for classes `text-muted` and `text-primary`

Answer (score -1):

There are some problems with your code. The var i your are trying to catch is changing, when firing the click events. I added an data attribute... Try something like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    var icons = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-baby");

    for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {

        icons[i].setAttribute("data-i", i);

        icons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {

            var index = parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-i"));

            if (index < 14) {
                this.classList.add("text-muted");
            } else {
                this.classList.toggle("text-primary");
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: This code only works for starting 15 inputs brother. Thanks for help

Comment: I want to select all the inputs but the selection limit will be 14.

Comment: `index === 14`  will never work, becaus index is a string

Comment: OK. The logic is not correct. Anyway a parseInt for MrJ ;-)

Comment: by the way he doesn't want this, the 14 should be everywhere, not only the 14 first places

Comment: @kmgt overcomplicated solution and doesn't work. No need to store the indices as an attribute.